# Index: Avoid duplicates in table when Status = 'S'

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, duplicates

Is there a way of avoid duplicate rows only when status = 'S'?
Example:

[image: table showing what I need to do.]

I tried to create an index "unique" but when status = 'N' it should allow duplicate, then it did not work correctly.

Any sugestions to avoid duplicates in SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could use [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_name ON tab(fk_client) WHERE status = 'S';
```

Comment: Wow... implementing a constraint using an index, when a constraint cannot be written/implemented. This goes against one of my cardinal rules. Ugly, but can't deny it works. I'm impressed. +1

Comment: @TheImpaler Well, partial indexes are suitable in such scenario. [Partial unique index](https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html): `This provides a mechanism for enforcing uniqueness across some subset of the rows in a table.`

Comment: It's that I have this mantra of "use constraints, not indexes to enforce constraints". But this one clearly breaks this rule. You learn something new every day, I guess.

Comment: Why have that rule though? At least in SQL Server, unique constraints are enforced with a unique index so the distinction send artificial to me.